# How to convert mp3 to pcm

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

The mpmediaitem information must be converted to a byte array stream for server upload. So the code below

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/sourceclimber/34c1b831fb0f31f5ade9c62870ea33f9)

```
async void SoundPickingMedia(object sender, ItemsPickedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.MediaItemCollection.Items != null)
            foreach (var item in args.MediaItemCollection.Items)
            {
                var settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(new object[]
                {
                    NSNumber.FromUInt32((int)AudioFormatType.LinearPCM),
                    NSNumber.FromFloat(44100.0f),
                    NSNumber.FromUInt32(16),
                    NSNumber.FromUInt32(2),
                    NSNumber.FromBoolean(false),
                    NSNumber.FromBoolean(false),
                    NSNumber.FromBoolean(false)
                },
                new object[]
                {
                    AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
                    AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
                    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                    AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                });

                NSError outError;
                byte[] src;
                int size = 0;
                using (var asset = new AVUrlAsset(item.AssetURL))
                using (var assetReader = new AVAssetReader(asset, out outError))
                using (var assetOutput = new AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(asset.Tracks[0], settings))
                {                     

                    if (outError != null)
                        return;

                    if (!assetReader.CanAddOutput(assetOutput))
                        return;

                    assetReader.AddOutput(assetOutput);

                    if (!assetReader.StartReading())
                        return;
                    using (var allData = new NSMutableData())
                    {
                        while (assetReader.Status != AVAssetReaderStatus.Completed)
                        {
                            using (var buffer = assetOutput.CopyNextSampleBuffer())
                            {
                                if (buffer == null)
                                    continue;
                                using (var blockbuffer = buffer.GetDataBuffer())
                                {
                                    if (blockbuffer == null)
                                        continue;
                                    size = (int)(blockbuffer.DataLength);
                                    if (size <= 0)
                                        continue;
                                    using (var data = NSMutableData.FromLength((nint)size))
                                    {
                                        var err = blockbuffer.CopyDataBytes(0, (uint)size, data.MutableBytes);
                                        if (err != CMBlockBufferError.None)
                                            continue;
                                        allData.AppendData(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        src = allData.ToArray();
                    }
                }
             }
          }
```

But the byte array is not played. In my opinion, you need to convert pcm to mp3, etc. xamarin How to convert in c# environment?

In fact, pcm data may work well. If the pcm does not work properly, you should think back to the beginning. T.T.

Answer (score 0):

PCM is an encoding scheme,not a file format.If you want to convert your voice to mp3 .I recommend that you can use the package [NAudio.Lame](https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame) from the Nuget.

```
using System.IO;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Lame;

public static class Codec
{
 // Convert WAV to MP3 using libmp3lame library
 public static void WaveToMP3(string waveFileName, string mp3FileName, int bitRate = 128)
  {
    using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(waveFileName))
    using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3FileName, reader.WaveFormat, bitRate))
        reader.CopyTo(writer);
  }

 // Convert MP3 file to WAV using NAudio classes only
 public static void MP3ToWave(string mp3FileName, string waveFileName)
  {
    using (var reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3FileName))
    using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(waveFileName, reader.WaveFormat))
        reader.CopyTo(writer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lucas Zhang But the key is to create an mp3 mpmediaitem using the audio library mpmediapickercontroller. pcm data is only one of the processes. Do you know Lucas Zhang? How to convert mpmediaItem to WAV or MP3

Comment: I can provide you with music, but it is probably a useless mp3 file. There is an API in my application that uploads data to aws in byte [] format, and Android has already been tested.